# How to get my desired results in Android Sqlite Search LIKE % where search key word in bangla language

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-sqlite

1. cursor = sqLiteDatabase.query(MyTableName, allColumns,
   Database.COLUMN_TO + " LIKE ?", new String[]{"%বিবেচন%" }, null, null, null);

myMeaning="বিবেচন";

2. cursor = sqLiteDatabase.query(MyTableName, allColumns,
   Database.COLUMN_TO + " LIKE ?", new String[] {"%"+myMeaning+"%"}, null, null, null);

**The first gives my desired result. I want to know why the second one can not give the desired result?**

Comment: Can you turn on sqlite logs and show what real query was executed. by terminal commands:                                                                                                                     
               ```adb shell setprop log.tag.SQLiteLog V                                                                             
                   adb shell setprop log.tag.SQLiteStatements V```                                          you can see what sqlite excecute in logcat .

Comment: I got it, thanks. above two result is same. solved by assign the correct value in my Meaning variable.

Comment: Did you solve your problem ? And what was wrong ?

Comment: yes, problem was variable in myMeaning variable which is myMeangin="বিবচন"; not "বিবেচন";................Thanks

Comment: I want turn of sqlite logs ..please give the command ..By searching i did not get proper cmd.

Comment: To turn of sqlite logs use command like: `shell setprop log.tag.SQLiteLog E` and  `adb shell setprop log.tag.SQLiteStatements E` - in this command `E` = log level error and `V` is log level verbose

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved, problem was in myMeaning variable which is myMeangin="বিবচন"; not "বিবেচন"